# xsl:copy-of excluding parent

Tags: xslt

What code could I use in replace of `<xsl:copy-of select="tag"/>`, that when applied to the following xml..

```
<tag>
  content
  <a>
    b
  </a>
</tag>
```

..would give the following result: ?

```
content
<a>
  b
</a>
```

I wish to echo out all the content therein, but excluding the parent tag

---

*Basically I have several sections of content in my xml file, formatted in html, grouped in xml tags

I wish to conditionally access them & echo them out

For example: `<xsl:copy-of select="description"/>`

The extra parent tags generated do not affect the browser rendering, but they are invalid tags, & I would prefer to be able to remove them

Am I going about this in totally the wrong way?*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you want to include the `content` part as well, you'll need the `node()` function, not the `*` operator:

```xml
<xsl:copy-of select="tag/node()"/>
```

I've tested this on the input example and the result is the example result:

```xml
content
<a>
  b
</a>
```

Without hard-coding the root node name, this can be:

```xml
<xsl:copy-of select="./node()" />
```

This is useful in situations when you are already processing the root node and want an exact copy of all elements inside, excluding the root node. For example:

```
<xsl:variable name="head">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('head.html')" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$head" mode="head" />

<!-- ... later ... -->

<xsl:template match="head" mode="head">
  <head>
  <title>Title Tag</title>
  <xsl:copy-of select="./node()" />
  </head>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3):

Complementing Welbog's answer, which has my vote, I recommend writing separate templates, along the lines of this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="description" />
  </body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="description">
  <div class="description">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```